# How can I access an existing byte[] in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays

I have a small issue accessing a `byte[]`:
I have a binary object (`byte[]` saved to mssql db) which I get from the db and I want to read it. Whenever I access it, for its length or for its Read() method, I get a `Cannot access a closed Stream` exception.
What's the best way to treat binaries if they have to be updated in the code and than saved again to the db?

Thanks.

**Edit - code**
In this application we convert a test object to a generic data object we've created to simplify, so this is the data object:

```
public class DataObject
{
    public Stream Content { get; set; }
    public Descriptor Descriptor { get; set; }
}
```

The descriptor contains metadata only (currently only name and description strings) and is not relevant, I think.
The test is more complicated, I'll start by adding the mapping into data object. The serializer mentioned is `NetDataContractSerializer`.

```
public DataObject Map(Test test)
{
    using(var stream = new MemoryStream())
    {
        Serialize(test, stream);
        return new DataObject { Content = stream, Descriptor = test.Descriptor };
    }
}
 private void Serialize(Test test, MemoryStream stream)
 {
    serializer.WriteObject(stream, test);
    stream.Flush();
    stream.Position = 0;
 }
```

and vice versa:

```
public Test Build(DataObject data)
{
      using (var stream = data.Content)
      {
           var test = Deserialize(stream);
           test.Descriptor = data.Descriptor;
           return test ;
      }
}
private Test Deserialize(Stream stream)
{
    return serializer.ReadObject(stream) as IPythonTest;
}
```

**Edit II - trying to change the test's content:**
This is my first attempt handling streams, I'm not sure I'm doing it right, so I'll explain first what I want to do: The information in `data` field should be saved into the test's data object.

```
private static void UpdateTestObject(DataObject data, Test test)
{
    var testData = new byte[data.Content.Length];
    data.Content.Read(testData, 0, (int) data.Content.Length);
    test.TestObject = testData;
}
```

The exception is thrown in `UpdateTestObject` when accessing data.Content.  I get it after creating some test, mapping it, and trying to save it.

Comment: Are you going to share code or should we just suggesting how are you reading a stream?

Comment: You appear to be involving a `Stream`, but talking about a "binary object" and `byte[]` - some code could unmuddy the waters.

Comment: A `byte[]` doesn't have a `Read()` method. If you actually have a `Stream`, please be explicit in showing how how obtain this `Stream` (and when/how you try to manipulate it)

Comment: So, in which line are you getting the exception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the problem is caused by the `Map()` method - as far as I could understand, since it used:

```
using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
{ ... }
```

The stream was disposed of at the end of the block. Changing it to declaring a `MemoryStream` and then using it afterwards worked.
Thanks to everyone who gave it a thought (not mentioning reading all this code)! :)

Answer (score 0):

> data.Content.Read(testData, 0, (int) data.Content.Length);

Here we go. The data object has a Content stream that it closed.

Result: Error.

Reasno? TOTALLY (!) unrelated to your question. Basically find out why / what is the problem there in your data handling.

Could be a design fubar in which the stream is not available after a certain point and youru sage of the object is past this point.